# How to add attachments to todoTasks using Microsoft Graph API v1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add an attachment to a task using Graph API. Previously you can create and list attachments using Outlook Tasks enpoints in Outlook rest API and Graph API beta.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlooktask-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

However these are going to be deprecated soon and I am unable to find an equivalent feature in Graph Api v1.0.

Anyone knows how to do this in  Microsoft To Do API? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same queston. It looks like it is not possible yet with the current 1.0 GraphApi. There is a feature request in Microsoft's techcommunity, feel free to upvote:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/implement-todo-task-attachment-apis-in-microsoft-graph-api/idi-p/3061321

Comment: This is "me too" and a link to not an answer and an advertisment asking for an upvote. This needs a lot of editing to even get close to [ask]. Please delete it or improve it.